# Jquery UI Sortable element with smooth transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

is there a way to smooth the movement of the objects in the background when I drag an element to another position? Much like what happens when I drag one icon on iPhone: the others smoothly move either to the left or to the right of the icon I'm moving. This is my code now:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

It's very simple, like the one in the [JQuery UI demo](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid).